# correlation and "significance"

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have a data set of motions of different particles and I am interested if the direction they are going through have 'directional' correlation to each other. The results I am getting are not 'very convincing/ not very good'. For example, correlations of around 0.40-0.60, but this is up for interpretation.

It was suggested, however, to check if two particles doing some random motion would have such correlation. I haven't done it yet, and I don't know what the results would be.

I would like to ask for your insights on the following matters: 
1. If for example, the directional correlation of two seemingly random walkers will have a really low correlation (say ~0.1), versus our 0.4-0.6 in the premise, what would this say? Would this mean that our correlation did not happen by chance?

Comment: Could you explain what "directional correlation" is and how you compute it?  And please tell us what information is in your dataset: how exactly do you record a "motion"?

Comment: The concept of directional correlation came from this paper: https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v464/n7290/pdf/nature08891.pdf

Comment: For two particles $i,j$ with a normalized velocity $\mathbf{v}$, we are able to take the 'directional correlation' over time $t$ and time delay $\tau$. Mathematically, $C = < \textbf{v}_i(t)\cdot \textbf{v}_j (t+\tau) >_t$.

By taking the dot products of the velocities and averaging them over time $t$, the time delay $\tau$ that produces the maximum correlation is its time delay. Intuitively, we can say that if $C = 0.9$ for particle $i$ and $j$ with $\tau = 5$, then we can say that particle $i$ leads particle $j$ by 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you: those descriptions are clear and helpful.  I suspect the answers depend on details of the particles you are studying, how you measure them, and how frequently you do so. For instance, if velocities are estimated by differencing measurements of positions over relatively long time intervals, then the directional correlation of independently moving particles should be close to zero. If the velocities are measured at a high frequency over a short period for particles subject to Newton's laws (that is, with inertially limited accelerations) then they might seem to be correlated.